# Testing quotes in Json with xUnit in C# .Net

Tags: c#, json

I have an assignment where I have to write some code based on some tests. Basically the tests are written and I have to write the code so the test will pass.
I know that it may be a stupid question but I tried everything I could think off and searched everywhere (sorry if there is a related post here but I couldn't find it.)
So I have multiple tests but with the following two I can't understand.
The first one would be:

```
[Fact]
    // This is the test
    public void IsWrappedInDoubleQuotes()
    {
        Assert.True(IsJsonString(Quoted("abc")));
    }

    //And this is the method I wrote to pass the test
    static bool DoubleQuoted(string input)
    {
        return input.StartsWith("\"") && input.EndsWith("\"");
    }
```

Everything looked clear until now. One of the following tests is:

```
[Fact]
    public void HasStartAndEndQuotes()
    {
        Assert.False(IsJsonString("\""));
    }
```

I can't figure it out why the same function doesn't work on this one. It fails. (I have around 21 test to write code for, just string not including numbers and math operators).

Both of them have start and end quotes and that's why is so confusing. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: "Both of them have start and end quotes" - yes, but *at different positions*. While it's true that the single-character string `"` does start and end with a double-quote, it's not a valid JSON string.

Comment: It's unclear what this has to do with Json.NET, by the way. Presumably the point is for you to write bits of your own JSON implementation, not use Json.NET.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to Json and thought that it is related with Json.Net.

Comment: Json.NET (aka Newtonsoft.Json) is *one implementation* of JSON for .NET. If you're not using Newtonsoft.Json anywhere, I'd suggest removing the tag from your question.

Comment: I removed the tag, thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming you've written the `IsJsonString` implementation, and `DoubleQuoted` is one of the criteria you're using in that method to determine whether the input is valid JSON, right?

I'm also assuming `Quoted` wraps the given input in double-quotes, so `abc` is converted into `"abc"`, which is a valid string representation.

In the second test, `Quoted` isn't called on the input, so you're passing in a single character: `"`. (`\"` is just a way of telling C# that you actually mean a `"` and you're not trying to end the string literal in the C# context.) Two of those together would "start and end with quotes" (`""`) and be a valid JSON string, but a single `"` isn't a complete string literal. The criteria you've defined in `DoubleQuoted` recognizes that it technically starts with double-quotes and ends with double-quotes, but it doesn't take into account whether they are the *same* instance of double-quotes.

Comment: Yes, those are some criteria that I'm using. This makes a lot of sense now. So in addition, if for example in the first string "abc" , if the string would've been "\"abc\""  then abc is still converted to "abc" or is converted to ""abc"" ?

Comment: Right. `IsJsonString("\"abc\"")` would pass a string containing the text `"abc"` to `IsJsonString`, which would give you a `true` result.